# Query Dynamo from Lambda using Node - missed key

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I am using Lambda (nodeJS 4.3) to query my DynamoDB with the following:

```
var params = {
    TableName : "shoes",
    KeyConditionExpression: "gender = :gender AND support = :support AND terrain = :terrain",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":input": inputGender,
        ":input": inputSupport,
        ":input": inputTerrain
    }
}
```

When this runs I am getting an error that I am missing "Query condition missed key schema element: Id". It may just be a fundamental misunderstanding on my part, but if I want to query 2 or more of the fields in the DynamoDB do I need to make them a key or create indexes on all of them??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A **query** must include the partition key of the table (or a global secondary index). Your table's partition key is `id` and you didn't include that in the query. Given the query you are trying to run I don't think it makes sense to create a GSI on your table. You will need to perform a [full table scan](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html) operation instead of a query operation.

Comment: It may be my fundamental misunderstanding of Dynamo (first timer), but I basically have a user selecting 3 fields and then want to query Dynamo for the result. The partition key is an ID right now and the user will never obviously know this to query it. This is obviously super simple in a traditional SQL since "SELECT * FROM Tbl WHERE row1 = X OR row2 = Y OR row3 = Z" type of thing. Any guidance on translating this type of thinking to Dynamo?

Comment: also when I run it now I am getting "Conditions can be of length 1 or 2 only","

Comment: Not sure what else to tell you. Did you read my answer? You definitely have a fundamental misunderstanding of how to perform this type of lookup in DynamoDB. You need to do a **scan** instead of a query. You are trying to treat DynamoDB like a SQL database, which it isn't. I suggest taking the time to read the documentation and understand the differences. If you are just looking for someone to fix the code for you at least show more of your code in your question.

Comment: Yup, no worries. Reading up on scan now. Thank you for sending me down the right path.